# How to solve the collision of TAB key mapping of `UltiSnips` plugin in the Vim

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I've set the mapping keys as follows:

```
" Easy indent for code blocks
  nmap <tab>      v>
  nmap <s-tab>    v<
  vmap <tab>      >gv
  vmap <s-tab>    <gv
```

That works good. But, when I installed `UltiSnips` by vundle, the Tab key does't work as indent action, it will remove multi-line codes which I selected. I know this is because the default setting of `UltiSnips`. I would like to remain the Tab mapping for `UltiSnips` to trigger its functions, How do I solve the problem of using the TAB key to indent code blocks? Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Looking at UltiSnips documentation via `:h UltiSnips-triggers` says this:

```
You can define the keys used to trigger UltiSnips actions by setting global
variables. Variables define the keys used to expand a snippet, jump forward
and jump backwards within a snippet, and list all available snippets in the
current expand context. The variables with their default values are: >
   g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger               <tab>
   g:UltiSnipsListSnippets                <c-tab>
   g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger          <c-j>
   g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger         <c-k>
```

So set something like this in your ~/.vimrc` file:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<f5>'
```

However you may want to reconsider your `<tab>` mappings. I suggest you remove them and use `>>` or `<<` in normal mode and `>` or `<` in visual mode to do the initial indent/un-indent then repeat the action via `.`, the redo command. If you ever indent/un-indent too far then just undo it via `u`.

For more help see:

```
:h >>
:h .
:h u
```

Comment: In my case `tab` collided with the supertab plugin. Note if you're using vim over putty then certain key combos may not work out of the box such as `<f5>` or `<c-tab>` in that case try something like `let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<c-j>'` which also has the benefit of being more comfortable to type than `<c-tab>`

Comment: @PeterRincker When I use any function key e.g. `<f5>`, it just types `<f5>` while in insert mode. It works in gvim, however. But my problem with Putty persists :/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default expand trigger  to other key, but I think It's better to use maps as follow:

```
nnoremap > v>
nnoremap < v<
vnoremap > >gv
vnoremap < <gv
```

It works well for me.

What's more, `<Tab>` remove multi-line codes which you selected is a feature of `UltiSnips`. You can use selected text in `UltiSnips` snippets. Have a look at [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/ultisnips-visual-placeholder/).